# Cannot enable Appcelerator Performance Management

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

According to this documentation, Appcelerator Performance Management should be enabled using Appcelerator Studio. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Performance_Management

I can see on my Dashboard that Performance has been added to my organization, but when I create an app with services enabled, Appcelerator Studio only enables Cloud and Analytics. I have no option to enable Performance.

[Appcelerator Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufKRp.png)

I have tried creating a brand new app, I have tried re-downloading Appcelerator Studio, and I've tried creating an app through the CLI. None of these attempts have worked. Is there something else I need to do to enable the Performance Service for my app?

I should also note that I have a trial Enterprise account. I am able to visit the tab for Appcelerator Performance Management on my dashboard, but I cannot enable Performance for the app through Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Appcelerator Performance Management is only available to Enterprise Subscription customers. If you do not have an Enterprise License, you cannot use it. See the second line on this page: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_Performance_Management

Ray

Comment: Thank you Ray, I actually do have a trial Enterprise account. I am able to see that Appcelerator Performance Management is available to me in the Dashboard, but I cannot enable it in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one reason for that - You have logged in with a trial Plan.

For trial/free plans, Performance and Test services won't be visible in Appcelerator studio.
Check this. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7528